# Can I store a sound file which is recorded by "MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION" in .wav format?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am using following code to record the sound in my Galaxy S2.

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);

But this code is storing it in .3ga file.

In my app, I need to find the maximum amplitude of the sound. But Java sound does not support the .3ga file. Can someone please tell me how can I tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AudioRecord to record the audio.

AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
    44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

recorder.startRecording();

Please have a look at http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/android-audio-recording-part-2

Comment: :) I wish it was that simple. But i have no control over user's phone. Please give some other options!

Comment: In this case, you should not have called MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION, because all it does is launching the recorder application. You should use AudioRecord to achieve this.

Comment: Is there any other way? Please let me know. A link with sample code would be more helpful